# How to access session bean in EJB

Tags: ejb, javabeans

I'm new to ejb. I've created the session bean in one computer. And i want to access that session bean from the another system. How to do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the EJB into implementation and client jars, deploy the EAR, create a vendor-specific binding for the EJB, copy the client jar (with the newly created stubs) to the other system, do a JNDI lookup of the bean, and use PortableRemoteObject.narrow.